# Uploading Motion Files to Google Drive using Raspbian and Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, google-drive-api, raspberry-pi, motion, raspbian

I've been playing around with Motion on my Rapsberry Pi running Raspbian and came across [this post](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2012/09/creating-a-motion-detecting-security-cam-with-a-raspberry-pi-part-2.html) that sounded like fun to do.

I've been trying to tweak the steps he lists to have it work with Raspbian, and as far as I know I should be good.  I installed GData using "sudo apt-get install python-gdata" And then I put the uploader.py and uploader.cfg files in /etc/motion and changed the motion.confg file to have the line 
on_movie_end /etc/motion/uploader.py /etc/motion/uploader.cfg %f

Am I missing something? Theoretically this should work on Raspbian right? What else has to be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have been following the guides you have referred to get this working on Raspbian and I had the same problem; Motion seems to work but the script never executes.

However, when i tried to run the script directly I got a permission error.
I ran the following to make the script executable.

chmod a+x /etc/motion/uploader.py

now it uploads the videos to Google drive (no emails though?)

hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but it might be a away of getting files uploaded to google drive in an easier way.

Have you had a look at grive, its a linux utility which can be used to sync a folder on your raspberry pi with a folder on google drive.

See this link for more info on how to setup and use grive on a raspberry pi.

http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2013/03/raspberry-pi-google-drive-grive.html

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with it quite a bit and this is what helped. First try to run this from terminal:

```
/etc/motion/uploader.py /etc/motion/uploader.cfg /
```

Here you put the absolute path to your file you want to upload.

Try to run it, and if it asks you for a password you know you have a permission problem and need to change permissions so that it does not require the password to execute.

Try again. If it works then it will also work if you use this in `uploader.cfg`:

```
on_movie_end /etc/motion/uploader.py /etc/motion/uploader.cfg %f
```

Do not forget to uncomment this line! This sounds silly but it took me some time to realize it, i.e. `delete ;` that is in front of on_movie_end.

Another issue I had was the movie encoding. Only mpeg4 really worked for me.